# Regarding accountability

Tags: hadith, sharia

Theres a person who is dumb and partially deaf. He commits crimes but he has schizophrenia.
Is he accountable in the court according to shariah law?
Also can his testimony be accepted in courts since he is mentally incapable of speaking the truth?
I know the pen has been lifted from the fool according to islam, but is there anything prescribed for him in this world as punishment or something?